# In react router v4 why does BrowserRouter work only inside the main render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

For some reason I can't find a way to import the whole router as a component into the main `render` function that appends it to the body.

When I do this, all works fine:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <AppProvider store={store}/> // Containing the routing
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But when I move everything into `AppProvider` like this

```
render(
  <AppProvider store={store} history={history}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

AppProvider:

```
class AppProvider extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {...}
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.props.store}>
        <Router history={this.props.history}>
          /* ROUTES */
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AppProvider))
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Any ideas why?

Comment: What's the purpose of using `withRouter` there? I think that's what cause this issue.

Comment: Otherwise `render` doesn't work https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But a component which wrapped with `withRouter` should be always inside the Router tags. Otherwise, it simply can't function. It's usually used when we need router props inside our component.